# DynamoDB: How to use a query filter to check for conditions in a MAP

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table and the structure looks like this:

[image: DynamoDB document]

When I do a query, I would like to be able to do a query filter on the data map; but I'm not exactly sure how to setup the query.

This is what I have so far:

```
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> map = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
map.put("byUserId", new AttributeValue().withS("vl49uga5ljjcoln65rcaspmg8u"));

queryExpression
    .withQueryFilterEntry("data", new Condition()
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withM(map))
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS));
```

but the way I'm building the filter is not correct and I keep running into the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator CONTAINS is not valid for M AttributeValue type (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: CHIOME68L1HVGO81URD7CIOS6BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1077)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3106)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.query(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1118)
```

So what is a comparison operator I should be using (since IN is for list types), and how do I build the query filter such that I can specify a comparison inside of the MAP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try comparing the map attribute `data.byUserId` instead of the entire map structure:

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":x", "vl49uga5ljjcoln65rcaspmg8u");


QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withHashKey("HashKeyAttribute", "HashKeyAttributeValue")
    .withFilterExpression("data.byUserId = :x")
    .withValueMap(expressionAttributeValues);


ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```

Some important guidelines:

1. Make sure the variable `tableName` has the correct table name represented as a `string`.
2. Make sure to replace the string `HashKeyAttribute` with the attribute name that represents your `Hash Key`.
3. Make sure to replace the string `HashKeyAttributeValue` with the value that represents the Hash Key that you want to match.
4. Make sure the matched record has the `data.byUserId` with the value provided in the comparison expression. In the example the value `"vl49uga5ljjcoln65rcaspmg8u"` was provided.

Here is another example having the `id` attribute as the Hash Key:

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":x", "vl49uga5ljjcoln65rcaspmg8u");


QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withHashKey("id", "25g77vmummpr4mc5mb9vq36q43")
    .withFilterExpression("data.byUserId = :x")
    .withValueMap(expressionAttributeValues);


ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately it did not work. :(

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: What is the end result with the provided answer? Error? No results being returned?

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thank you so much! This worked great. Few things I would mention for future readers is that `data` is a reserved keyword. Once, I changed the attribute name, I was able to use @spin code.

Comment: I have one more question. I'm trying to refactor my code to use the high-level API. How do I set the expression attribute values? Is it possible to do in the high-level API? You can view my code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c1b11a9c5a79f6a599a).

Comment: I believe these guidelines on how to use placeholders will be helpful on this case: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html

Comment: Can condition be not used for nested attribute data. byUserId?